# Receive message when room member was kicked or his membership was revoked (when he is offline)

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

If room admin kick party member (or revoke his membership) when this members is **online**, other members will receive message about it.

If room admin kick party member (or revoke his membership) when this members is **offline**, other members will never receive message about it.

Is it possible to get presence message when offline user was kicked from room (or his membership was revoked)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is something that allows this in XEP-0045 Multi-User Chat specification.

You would need to customize the `mod_muc_room.erl` to add the non-standard behaviour you need.

Comment: So, just for now better solution is  periodically send request to get room members?

Comment: You did not say which problem you are trying to solve, so not sure. But having possibly large number of users doing polling on the room config does not seem a good solution to me. You should consider writing your own custom change as I mentioned.